# Generating a relation between three consecutive coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Let $$
\left(1+x+x^{2}\right)^{20}=\sum_{k=0}^{40} a_{k}\, x^{k}.
$$
If $\alpha a_{11}=\beta a_{10}+\gamma a_{9}$, where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{N}$ then the value of $\displaystyle\frac{\gamma-\alpha}{\beta}$ is.

> My method was first observing that $a_{40-k} = a_k$ and sum of even coefficients minus odd coefficients is $1$. From these can we deduce a recursion between $a_{k+1}$, $a_{k}$, and $a_{k-1}$. I tried to somehow connect using a roots of unity filter but the relation I am not getting.

Comment: You may find this useful: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrinomialCoefficient.html

Comment: Given the $\,a_{k-1},a_k,a_{k+1},\,$ and $\,\alpha a_{k+1} = \beta a_k + \gamma a_{k-1}\,$ __and__ also$\,\frac{\gamma-\alpha}{\beta} \in \mathbb{N},\,$ then this quotient is determined uniquely and does __not__ depend on $\,k.$

Comment: Do we know that the quotient has to be a natural number? Also I don't see how the coefficient could be independent of $k$. For $k=1$ the three $a$ values are $(1, 20, 210)$, and for $k=2$ they're $(20,210, 1520)$. I don't see how you're going to get the same ratios for both sets of coefficients.

Comment: In fact, following up, $az =bx+cy$ defines an infinite plane of points for a tuple $(a,b,c)$. That plane intersects the origin, so there are an infinite number of solutions in every octant including Octant 1--and if there is one integer point, there are infinitely many. It seems to me that the solution can't be uniquely determined *at all*, unless the only integer solutions lie on a line radiating from the origin. That situation seems highly unlikely for any positive integer $(a,b,c)$ that you could choose.

Comment: Yes @EricSnyder you are right but we should probably get the alpha ,beta values from the recurrence not in general

Comment: @somos i agree but check my recent comment

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Notice that the LHS is the generating function of the number of solutions to $y_1+y_2+\dots+y_{20}=k$ with $y_i \in \{0,1,2\}$ for each $i$.

Comment: Yes Sir i did that i mean isnt the three coefficient relation finding will be difficult here?

Comment: The value of $a_k$ is the number of such solutions, so try to find a recurrence relation for $a_k$.

Comment: Sir i am facing problem in the case when some of them would be 2 , as when we add 1 to it it becomes 3 so we need to reject those cases , i dont know how to get rid of that for k=10

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed via WolframAlpha that the system $$
\begin{cases}
2796\alpha = 1321\beta + 566\gamma \\
n = \frac{\gamma - \alpha}{\beta}
\end{cases}
$$

has an infinite set of positive integer solutions for a dozen or so positive integer and rational values of $n$. I suspect you can get any rational quotient $n$ you want from these conditions.

$6460 \cdot (2796,1321,566) = (a_{11}, a_{10}, a_9)$. This is the source of the constants used in the equations above.

Comment: Sir i think its the recurrence relation which the k-1,k,k+1 satisfies , from thst we get that alpha ,beta , gamma and put it otherwise i too agree that it can have infinie values .

Comment: I'm uncertain why you think there's a recurrence relation here? There's a generalized recurrence that comes from the trinomial triangle, but it's a row-to-row recurrence. It's possible there might be an in-row recurrence that I didn't notice. But the recurrence should still give you $(a_{11},a_{10}, a_9) = (18062160, 8533660, 3656360)$. I do notice I made a typo which I'll correct, but the equations work just as well for $2769$ as for $2796$, the correct coefficient.